# Automatic saving of a pdf attachment ( type application/pdf) from a specific sender into another pdf type attachment ( either /A or /X pdf type

Tags: pdf, types

I have a supplier that sends in pdfs generated by Artifex Ghostscipt 8.54 PDF Writer. It sends into an application/pdf format not compatible with pdf viewer in power apps..Microsoft support cannot resolve the issue either..
I tried to open and save into either an archivable /A or /X type pdf and it solves the problem !
Thus I am looking for a way to
Whenever there is an email coming in from a specific sender into the inbox with a pdf file attached:
automatically replace the attachment into another pdf type in the email
Thanks for any help

Comment: In which programming language do you want to implement that? And can you share an example of those *not compatible* pdfs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for taking time to help.. Could be a vba executable directly in outlook  I am trying to see how to add an example of the document.. Mail come from a sender like "supplier_NoReply@supplier.com"

Comment: *"Could be a vba executable directly in outlook"* - Hhmmm, unfortunately that is not my area of expertise, I'm more at home with Java or C#. Also whoever might feel up to the task most likely will need an example of those *not compatible pdfs* to analyze and use as test file.